# How to prove differentiability and continuity for piecewise function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

Given the following piecewise function: $f(x)$

\begin{cases} 
      x \sin x & x\ \in \mathbb Q \\
      0 & x \in \mathbb {R/Q} 
   \end{cases}
Prove/Disprove:
a) $f(x)$ is continuous
b) $f(x)$ is differentiable

I am having trouble using the Epsilon-Delta definition given that there is always an irrational number between rational numbers, so I'm assumung that I need to construct a sequence that converges to an x $\in \mathbb {Q}$ but these sequences  $(x_{n})_n$ could also theoretically be $\in \mathbb {R/Q}$?

Comment: Do you mean continuity and differentiability at $x=0$?

Comment: Your trouble seems to be that you're trying to prove something that isn't true. Try disproving it instead.

Comment: ... though there are a few points where the function is continuous, and exactly one point where it is differentiable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Are you certain the function is not differentiable at the nodes $x = n\pi$?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite: Yes I am, since that those points (for $n\ne 0$) the derivative of $0$ and the derivative of $x\sin x$ are different.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Ah yes!

Answer (score 2):

It's worth doing some investigating before throwing ourselves at the problem.

Pick a point $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then either $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. We can start by looking at $c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose that $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $(x_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence with $x_n \in \left(c, c+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}) $. Then $\lim x_n = c$ but $f(x_n) = 0$. So unless $c=0$, there is no way the function could be continuous there.
For $c=0$, the function is actually continuous! You can show this using $\epsilon-\delta$.

Now we can start looking at irrational points. Let $r\in\mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Obviously, unless we have $r\sin(r)=0$, the function has no chance of being continuous. The points where this happens are the $r = n\pi$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Again, the function is continuous at these points, I will let you think about why .

At $c=0$, the function is differentiable. You can show this using the linear approximation definition of differentiability: put $$R(h) = \begin{cases} 0,\quad \quad x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \\ \sin(x),\quad x \in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases} $$

Then $R(h) \to 0 $ as $h\to0$. Furthermore $$f(h) = f(0) + 0h + R(h)h$$

So the derivative of $f(x)$ at $0$ is $0$.

Now at points $c\ne0$ where the function is continuous, the function is not differentiable (thanks @Henning Makholm). You can see this by taking two sequences that tend to that those points, one of rational numbers and of irrational numbers, and see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n-c}$ is different for both sequences, hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: Nice and simple explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

This function is discontinuous. For instance, take a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of irrational numbers such that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}q_n=1$. Then$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}f(q_n)=0\text{ and }f\left(\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}q_n\right)=\sin(1)\neq0.$$Since it is discontinuous, it is not differentiable.

Comment: I think it should be thee other way: $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @57Jimmy I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: This is wrong I believe, see my answer.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite What's wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos While it is true the function is discontinuous at 1, it is continuous and even differentiable at other points.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite I know that. But if function is continuous if it is continuous at every point of its domain and it is differentiable if it is differentiable ar every point of its domain. Since in is netheir continuous nor differentiable at $1$, $f$ is neither continuous nor differentiable. I really don't see anyting wrong here.

Comment: Ah I see, well that makes the whole exercise a bit less interesting, but the question does ask what the question asks